# Multiple problems have ocurred (Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

When I create a new project the Eclipse shows me this message:

[image]

[image]

The details:

```
parseSdkContent failed
Could not initialize class android.graphics.Typeface
```

And this happens when I trying to running an existing project:

[image]

I deleted the `.metadata` folder and restarted my IDE, because I got some similar problems. I don't know if this happens because a bad update of the SDK.

I'll appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Just reinstall and call it a day.

Comment: @323go How can I delete completely Eclipse and the elements installed by this (temp files, registers, downloads, etcetera)?

Answer (score 1):

Just drag & drop it to the bottom & corner of the screen, so that it cannot be visible, & continue your work. Eclipse is full of bugs, 1 problem you solve then the another problem came, so I always use this to workaround for this type of prompt message, there is no harm in doing so...

Answer (score 0):

Deleted the `home/.android` folder.

In Windows you can find this folder in `C:/Users/User/`

Comment: And this let me work without problems? I restored my system, thinking that my Eclipse will be back to normality (but not happens).